# How to calculate the probability of 1 dimensional symmetric random walk to escape the ball?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

I'm struggling to calculate escaping probability of symmetric random walk with 1 dimension.
How to calculate the probability of symmetric random walk to exit the ball with radius n^{x} centered 0 after n steps?
Is there a paper related to this one?
I'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: A ball of radius $n^x$? What is $x$? Does $n$ represent the number of steps in this expression?

Comment: I'm sorry for  insufficient information. You are right. Let x be 0<x<1 and we consider n is  sufficiently large .

Comment: For each $1\leq j \leq n$ let $X_j$ be uniformly distributed on the set $\{-1,1\}$ and set $$S_n= X_1 + \dots + X_n$$ If $n$ is sufficiently large then $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \approx N(0,1)$ from central limit theorem. Then  $$ P\Big(|S_n|> n^x\Big)\approx P\Big(|Z|>n^{x-\frac{1}{2}}\Big)$$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$. If $x>\frac{1}{2}$ this probability tends to $0$ as $n \rightarrow\ \infty$. If $x<\frac{1}{2}$ this will tend to $1$. It appears that $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is your value of interest.

Comment: Is 'exist the ball' really supposed to be 'exits the ball'? Also is it a closed or an open ball?

Comment: When you say after n steps do you mean that you compare with a radius $1^{x}$ at step 1, $2^{x}$ at step 2, and so on and if it exited at any of those steps it counts, or do you just want to know what the probability it is outside $n^{x}$ at step $n$?

Comment: @open problem I'm assuming he or she means a ball of radius $n^x$ centered at $0$ to be the closed interval $[-n^x,n^x]$. So if $n=25$ and $x=1/2$ we're tasked to find the probability of leaving $[-5,5]$ after $25$ steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is also calculated by normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n} X_{j}$ be the position of the random walk on the number line.

The number of different walks of n steps where each step is +1 or −1 is $2^{n}$. For the simple random walk, each of these walks is equally likely. In order for $S_{n}$ to be equal to a number k it is necessary and sufficient that the number of +1 in the walk exceeds those of −1 by k. It follows +1 must appear $\frac{n + k}{2}$ times among n steps of a walk, hence the number of walks which satisfy $S_{n} = k$ equals the number of ways of choosing (n + k)/2 elements from an n element set. Notice that n+k must be even since n=j+k+j where j is the number of -1 steps, so $n+k = 2j + 2k$ and we get the formula.

$$P(S_{n}=k) = \frac{n!}{(n-\frac{n+k}{2})!(\frac{n+k}{2})!2^{n}}$$

Using a symmetry we get $P(S_{n}=k)=P(S_{n}=-k)$.

So for n and k even:

$$P(|S_{n}|\leq k) = \sum^{k/2}_{j=0}2 P(S_{n} = 2j) - P(S_{n} = 0) = - \frac{n!}{2^{n}(\frac{n}{2}!)^{2}} + 2\sum^{k/2}_{j=0} \frac{n!}{(n-\frac{n+2j}{2})!(\frac{n+2j}{2})!2^{n}}$$

Comment: There is this idea that at step 1, $S_{1}\in${-1,1} and so $S_{1}$ 'leaves' the ball (-1,1). Therefore the walk always leaves that growing ball on the first step. It probably isn't what the OP meant, since it is kinda lame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And then I can calculate it with stirling's approximation